# Comparable interface project

Tags: java, interface, comparable

I'm very stuck on a project, so far I have got:

```
public class MyInt implements Comparable<MyInt> {
    private int value;

    MyInt(int x) {
        value = x;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ("" + value);
    }

    public int intValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int compareTo(MyInt rhs) {
        MyInt myInt = (MyInt) rhs;
        int myInteger = myInt.intValue();
        int result = 0;
        if (value < myInteger) {
            result = -1;
        } else if (value == myInteger) {
            result = 0;
        } else {
            result = +1;
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

And this is the question:
Consider the following Java Library interface:

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
int compareTo(T rhs);
}
```

Complete the implementation of the class below that implements the above
interface (note this interface is automatically imported by java – do NOT
re-type it in your project). The compareTo method should return -1 if
value is less than rhs.value, 0 if both sides are equal and +1 if value is
greater than rhs.value.

```
public class MyInt implements Comparable<MyInt> {
private int value;
MyInt(int x) {...}
public String toString() {...}
public int intValue() {...}
public int compareTo(MyInt rhs){...}
}
```

Now I need to implement the comparable interface in another class which performs basic arithmetic with rational numbers, would it be best to use inheritance to achieve this?The class :

```
public class Rational {
    private int num;
    private int denom;

    public Rational() {
        this(0,1);
    }

    public Rational(int num, int denom) {
        this.num = num;
        this.denom = denom;
    }

    int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    int getDenom() {
        return denom;
    }

    public Rational add(Rational rhs) {
        return new Rational(num * rhs.denom + rhs.num * denom, denom * rhs.denom);
    }

    public Rational subtract(Rational rhs) {
        return new Rational(num * rhs.denom - rhs.num * denom, denom * rhs.denom);
    }

    public Rational multiply(Rational rhs) {
        return new Rational(num * rhs.num, denom * rhs.denom);
    }
public Rational divide(Rational rhs) {
    return new Rational(num * rhs.denom, denom * rhs.num);
}

public String toString() {
    String result;

    if (num == 0)
        result = "0";
    else if (denom == 1)
        result = num + "";
    else
        result = num + "/" + denom;

    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rational r1 = new Rational(1, 2); // 1/2
    Rational r2 = new Rational(3, 4);// 3/4
    Rational result = new Rational();
    result = r1.add(r2);
    System.out.println(result);

    Rational result1 = new Rational();
    result1 = r1.subtract(r2);
    System.out.println(result1);

    Rational result2 = new Rational();
    result2 = r1.multiply(r2);
    System.out.println(result2);

    Rational result3 = new Rational();
    result3 = r1.divide(r2);
    System.out.println(result3);

}
```

}

Comment: Uh... Yes, you have to compare the values and return -1, 0, or 1, just like you said.  What exactly is it that you don't understand about what you need to do?

Comment: First your need to ask yourself: 1) given a `MyInt` instance "rhs", how do I get the numeric (int) value? 2) how do I get the same `value` from inside the instance (in a method of `MyInt`) 3) how do I compare `int`s ?

Comment: As a side note: I see it's part of your spec to explicitly return 0, -1, or 1; under normal circumstances when dealing with `Comparable<T>` objects, don't take for granted the number will be exactly 1 or -1. The contract only requires that *some* negative or positive integer value ,or zero, will be returned. So, your checks should be `<`, `>`, or `==` to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare `this.intValue()` (the current instance) and `rhs.intValue()` (the "right hand side"). Comparing `rhs` to itself (by aliasing it to `myInt`) should always return 0. And storing the result as a temporary variable doesn't seem to server any purpose in your code. You could do something like

```
// MyInt myInt = (MyInt) rhs;
if (this.intValue() < rhs.intValue()) {
    return -1;
} else if (this.intValue() == rhs.intValue()) {
    return 0;
}
return 1;
```

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils You missed one of OP's requirements the *compareTo method should return -1 if value is less than rhs.value, 0 if both sides are equal and +1 if value is greater than rhs.value.*

Answer (score 0):

No need to do explicit casting of your parameter (MyInt rhs), and since you are simply comparing two integers, use static compare method from Integer:

```
 public int compareTo(MyInt rhs) {
     return Integer.compare(this.value, rhs.intValue());
 }
```

I would suggest to change your int field to Integer to avoid performance loss in autoboxing of primitives